# How safe is that to develop a simple linux kernel module/driver on my own machine?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver, drivers, methodology

I'm writing a simple kernel character device driver, and I wonder how safe is it to do it on my own machine's OS instead of on a VM.

Could a kernel panic be destructive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had these issues when I started writing device drivers.

1. System hangs - These happen to every kernel newbie. They're caused by the Linux kernel is doing useless work repeatedly. You won't even be able to move the mouse.
2. Kernel crashes - Messages like 'System program problem detected' appear when you boot into your system again.
3. As you start writing advanced drivers like network device drivers, your Ethernet or wireless cards may stop working. Restarting your system might fix this issue, but it might not.

A real kernel developer doesn't mess around with VMs. Don't be afraid to test and code on real machine. I compiled a separate kernel exclusively for testing device drivers. I have one kernel for testing and another for application programming.

If you want to test drivers on a newly built kernel, [this](http://kernelnewbies.org/KernelBuild) is a nice guide on installing a new kernel.

Answer (score 1):

It's generally safe. The worst thing that could happen in the majority of cases is you cause your kernel to fail to boot and have to select a different kernel in GRUB or whatever boot loader you are using. Just make sure to keep a known good kernel around in case this happens.

That is in the general case. Of course, if we get more specific then it gets more complicated. If you are hacking around a storage driver, could a crash corrupt some data? Definitely. If you are messing around with video drivers, could you output an invalid resolution/refresh rate to a screen potentially causing damage? Sure you could. Writing a driver to control a battery charger via SPI commands? Better not let it charge beyond the datasheet specs or you could cause a fire.

At the end of the day a VM is not a replacement for testing on real hardware. Just keep in mind what it is you are doing and the potential consequences of that change. Usually its nothing a reboot won't fix. In theory though, it IS possible to break something.